# ScanFilter in DynamoDB using BETWEEN comparisonOperator

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, filter, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to use the ScanFilter to filter a date using dynamoDB.
I tried looking in the docs but can't find how to structure the JSON format.
Currently I have:

```
 "params": {
    "TableName": "steprstatus2",
    "ScanFilter": {
      "lastModified": {
        "ComparisonOperator": "BETWEEN",
        "AttributeValueList": [
          "Wed, 10 Oct 2018 21:09:23 GMT", "Fri, 12 Oct 2018 21:09:23 GMT"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure what should go in the AttributeValueList, or if I have to modify my date to be a specific format in DynamoDB itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I needed to use the BETWEEN comparison operator instead and provide comma separated values in my array of the same data type:

```
 "ScanFilter": {
      "lastModified": {
        "ComparisonOperator": "BETWEEN",
        "AttributeValueList": [
            "Wed, 10 Oct 2018 00:02:59 GMT",
            "Wed, 10 Oct 2018 23:46:34 GMT"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the ScanFilter AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.ScanFilter.html), the AttributeValueList is specified as an array of type -> value maps.

In your case, the array would look something like this:

```
"AttributeValueList": [
  {"S": "Wed, 10 Oct 2018 21:09:23 GMT"},
  {"S": "Fri, 12 Oct 2018 21:09:23 GMT"}
]
```

Note that [the Date type is stored as an S (String) DynamoDB type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html).

Comment: i got "One or more parameter values were invalid: Invalid number of argument(s) for the CONTAINS ComparisonOperator" when i tried this, maybe this syntax is only for aws cli and not actual json?

Comment: The ScanFilter in your question only shows a BETWEEN ComparisonOperator. The [Condition AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html) can help you with CONTAINS. It looks like CONTAINS can only have one non-list/map/set argument (which is different from BETWEEN, which requires two values).

Answer (score 0):

Use `BETWEEN` in `FilterExpression` with `scan` query.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();


let queryParams = {
  TableName: 'tableName',
  FilterExpression: '#lastModified BETWEEN :startTime AND :endTime',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':startTime': '2018-06-26T18:10:00.000Z',
    ':endTime': '2018-06-27T18:10:00.000Z'
  },
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#lastModified': 'lastModified' },
  ScanIndexForward: false
};

documentClient.scan(queryParams, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('failure:scan data from Dynamo error', err);
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('success:scan data from Dynamo data');
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm trying not to use FilterExpression because I can't use it in conjunction with scanFilter, and i have multiple filters I am using with scanFilter. It might be possible to move all filters using FilterExpression but i'd like to use scanFilter alone if possible